# Applying different functions to data classified qualitatively

Tags: python, excel

So I'm a python newbie and making the transition over from laborious excel spreadsheets. I have some geological data that has been classified using a qualitative method, for example 1= gravel, 2= sand etc, with intermediate values between classifiers given by a decimal, so like mostly sand but some gravel would be 1.3, or 1.4 etc.

Each distinct major grouping has an integer value that serves as a sort of cutoff; I want to apply a different formula/function to each group based on some kind of IF in-between statement.

Normally in excel I would do this by nesting logic statements such as "For values < 1, do ...., for >=1 but <2 do ...." etc

Can anyone point me to some tutorials on how to do this efficiently in python?

Thanks

Comment: You are looking to implement a simple for loop and some simple conditionals (if statements). I can thoroughly recommend reddit.com/r/learnpython as a place to start. Youtube (and google in general) is your friend there are some great tutorials. Just try typing "Python basic if statement" and keep clicking until it makes sense! If you try something and it doesn't work, try and use the search function to see if someone else has had a similar problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thats basic python so this might help: https://www.learnpython.org

It would definitely make sense to learn a bit about data structures and how python handles those as well as maybe Object Oriented Programming. Python will do things like this without you having to write many lines of code. 
Enjoy learning python!

To get you started you might want to use a dictionary to assign your material to a number: 
materials={"gravel":1,"sand":2,...}

Comment: Ok fair enough!